# asp.net C# - DataList2 Refresh based on the value of DataList1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and C#.  I want to refresh the 2nd DataList (DataList2) when a user clicks on the (+) sign.

Datalist1 will list all Company records with a column that has a (+) sign.  If a user clicks the (+), it will expand (DataList2) below the company and list all the contact names.

Please help.  Thanks!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CompanyList.aspx.cs" Inherits="_CompanyList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="/Apps/ERP/ERP_Styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table  style="width:100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%"></td>
                <td style="width:60%"> 
                    <p class="PageTitle">Company List</p> 

                </td>
                <td style="width:20%">               
                    <asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Click me" 
                    OnClientClick="window.parent.location.href='/Apps/ERP/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx'; return false;" /> 
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>       

        <%--  ////////////////////////////////////// Start Data Row  ///////////////////////////////////////// --%>               
        <table width="595px">
            <asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyList"  runat="server" Width="100%">     
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="+" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'
                            OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"  
                            ></asp:LinkButton>    
                      </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("Row")%></td>
                      <td><%#Eval("Company")%></td>
                   </tr>
                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server">
                       <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Width="100%">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <tr>
                                  <td><%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
                                  <td><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>                        
                               </tr>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:DataList>
                   </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </table>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCompanyList" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnApps %>"

                SelectCommand="SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By MatchFlag ASC) AS ROW
                                , Company FROM (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT(Company) AS Company, MatchFlag
                                    --,InsertFlag, MatchFlag
                                    FROM dbo.Import_CompanyContact icc 
                                    WHERE RefNum = @RefNum
                                    AND MatchFlag = 2
                                ) a  "              
                > 

                <SelectParameters> 
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter  Name="RefNum" QueryStringField="RefNum" DefaultValue="0" Type="Int16" /> 
                </SelectParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>  

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _CompanyList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //pass index of item in command argument
        int itemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);      

        //depending on your needs bind the details on demand
        //or preload during ItemDataBound 

        Panel childViewPanel = (Panel)DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("pnlChildView");
        if (childViewPanel != null)
        {
            //toggle visibility of childViewPanel and bind child list if panel is visible

            if (childViewPanel.Visible)
            {
                DataList childList = (DataList)childViewPanel.FindControl("DataList2");
                if (childList != null)
                {
                    int keyValue = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[itemIndex];

                    //bind the list using DataList1 data key value
                    childList.DataSource = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.Import_CompanyContact WHERE Company = 'Applied Micro'"; //get data using keyValue
                    childList.DataBind();
                }  
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things needed to make this work for you, but first - **please** consider using stored procedures or at least parameterized queries.

You are attempting to access the `.DataKeys` of the "parent" `DataList` but you never included that on your definition.  In order to accurately do this, you're going to need to change your source query to include some key value (instead of just `ROW_NUMBER()` (not a key) and `Company`):

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" 
  id="DataList1" 
  DataSourceID="dsCompanyList"  
  runat="server" 
  Width="100%" 
  DataKeyField="YourKeyField">
```

Then, you'll need to alter your code-behind to set the `.DataSource` of your "child" `DataList`...and while I'm using your query, please consider using something other than dynamic SQL:

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int itemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Panel childViewPanel = (Panel)DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("pnlChildView");
        if (childViewPanel != null)
        {
            if (childViewPanel.Visible)
            {
                DataList childList = (DataList)childViewPanel.FindControl("DataList2");
                if (childList != null)
                {
                    int keyValue = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[itemIndex];
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.Import_CompanyContact WHERE Company = " + keyValue, con))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                childList.DataSource = dr;
                                childList.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain this. I will work on this.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it works now. Thanks again for that. Is that a way that I can make the (+) in the LinkButton1 become (-) when the ChildList expanded? and then user click on the (-) sign, the pnlChildView or ChildList disappear and (+) come back?

Comment: Absolutely. I could be wrong, but I think SO would prefer you ask this as a new question (or search SO for existing questions that might already address your problem).